# Checking condition over a window in pandas series

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas series (`jp`) that I am moving a window over to check a condition. The series looks like this:

```
0    54.0
1    0.0
2    13.0
3    316.0
4    342.0
```

In iterating throw the series and checking a condition:

```
jp_index = jp.index.tolist()
for i in jp_index:
    if any([jp[:i] > 6]):
        print('Hi!')
```

The following error is returned:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Condition: Starting from the first index, check any values from first index to current index is greater than 6.

Comment: What is the condition that you need to check? And also can you please explain the logic in little more details?